# Least Absolute Deviation

Tags: statistics, regression-analysis

Here is my data
X    90   86   67   89   81   75
Y 62 45 40 55 64 53

I have to find the Least Absolute Deviation of the data, however I am absolutely stomped. I picked (75,53) as my point after looking at the scatter plot on excel. From here on though I am completely confused as to how to proceed. If I could just get alittle push on where to go I'd be happy with that thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

*This is the first time I work with least absolute deviations regression; so, please, forgive me if I am off topic in this answer.*

If I refer to [Wikipedia - Least Absolute Deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations) and assume that we look for a linear model $$y=a+ bx$$ we need to minimize, with respect to $a$ and $b$ $$F=\sum_{i=1}^6 |a+b x_i-y_i|$$ Quoting the Wikipedia page *"unlike least squares regression, least absolute deviations regression does not have an analytical solving method; therefore, an iterative approach is required"*.

This is what I did using a minimizer (you could use Excel solver for it) using, as (poor) initial estimates the values obtained using a standard linear regression, that is to say minimizing $$G=\sum_{i=1}^6 (a+b x_i-y_i)^2$$ which would lead to $a=4.799$ and $b=0.595$.

Doing it, I ended with $a= -24.0869$ and $b=0.956521$.

In the table below, I reproduce the original values as well as those given by linear least squares $(LSQ)$ and least absolute deviations $(LAD)$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x & y & LSQ & LAD \\
 90 & 62 & 58.3206 & 62.0000 \\
 86 & 45 & 55.9419 & 58.1739 \\
 67 & 40 & 44.6429 & 40.0000 \\
 89 & 55 & 57.7259 & 61.0435 \\
 81 & 64 & 52.9684 & 53.3913 \\
 75 & 53 & 49.4003 & 47.6522
\end{array}
\right)$$